# Apache Airflow - dynamically generate number of BatchOperators (AWS) based on the number of files on AWS S3

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, aws-batch

I have a workflow that generates the number of `*.tif` files and saves on S3. Then there is a function that queries the content of the directory on S3 and returns it in arrays. According to this return value, there should be created a number of `BatchOperators` in DAG **dynamically** and each of the particular arrays should be assigned to BatchOperator as env variable.

Example:

- Return value of the function: `[[a.tif, b.tif], [c.tif, d.tif], [e.tif]]`
- according to this, there should be dynamically created 3 `BatchOperators`, with arrays passed as *env* variable to them

  - `BatchOperator1` - env var `[a.tif, b.tif]`
  - `BatchOperator2` - env var `[c.tif, d.tif]`
  - `BatchOperator3` - env var `[e.tif]`

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the .partial() and .expand() functions with the BatchOperators task. Input the constants to the partial, and then the elements to loop over in the expand() section as so:

```
list_to_print = ["Print", "Each", "Of", "These"]
def printList(list_to_print):
    for i in list_to_print:
        print(i)
        
task_print_list = PythonOperator.partial(
        task_id='print_list',
        ).expand(python_callable=printList(list_to_print))

task_print_list
```

This will loop over each element in the list. In your case you will want to pass the function that creates the list you've mentioned as the parameter in expand(). More documentation can be seen here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html